# BASH scripting - menu not showing echos

Tags: linux, bash, case, echo

I'm extremely new to this, but can anyone tell me why when I run this, it doesn't show my echo's?
It accepts all my inputs, but say when I do the subtraction one it doesn't display
echo  "$a - $b = $(($a-$b))"
It worked if I put an Exit after each case, but I would like it to keep going after it completes one input.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    clear
    cat <<EOF
        Please Select:
        Option 1. Quit
        Option 2. Display Options Again
        Option 3. Subtraction
        Option 4. Division
        Option 5. Who am I?
EOF
    read -p "Enter selection [1-5] > "
    case "$REPLY" in
        1)
           break 
           ;;
           
        2)
       ;;
        3)
           read -p "Enter the First Number: " a
       read -p "Enter the Second Number: " b
       echo  "$a - $b = $(($a-$b))" 
       ;;
           
        4)
       printf "Enter the First Number: "
       read   a
       printf "Enter the Second Number: "
       read   b
       echo  "$a / $b = $(($a/$b))" 
       ;;
           
        
        5)
       echo "My name is Michelle" 
       ;;
           
        *)
       echo "Invalid entry." 
       ;;
            
     esac
done
echo "Program terminated."
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel; look into the `select` built-in command.

Comment: The problem is that you have `clear` before the menu. So you're clearing the screen after printing the result.

Comment: Also, being consistent about using `read -p` versus printing out a prompt separately makes your code nicer.

Comment: Finally, your `clear` is to blame.

Comment: You do not have any pause after your substraction result is shown on screen and then your loop immediately go to next iteration with "clear" in the beginning

Comment: Maybe throw in a `sleep 10` at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the clear in the loop. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that the first command in the loop is `clear`. This removes the output immediately after it was displayed.